# Quem define as regras ortográficas entre Brasil e Portugal?

Tags: acordo-ortográfico

Existe algum órgão que une ambos países em relação aos acordos ortográficos ou simplesmente existe uma troca de propostas entre o que deve ou não ser aceito ou removido da ortografia de cada país?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe um órgão unificado da língua portuguesa. Existe a [Comunidade dos Países de Língua Portuguesa](http://www.cplp.org/), mas é uma organização de integração política internacional que não tem nenhuma intenção explícita de normatizar a língua escrita ou falada.

Existe, sim, um [Acordo Ortográfico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990) que unifica a ortografia das diferentes variações da língua portuguesa. Este acordo previa a criação de um vocabulário comum a ser utilizado por todos os países signatários. Porém, a divergência nos prazos de adoção do Acordo gerou uma discrepância na interpretação destes termos, e cada país resolveu lançar seu próprio vocabulário.

A Academia Brasileira de Letras publicou o [Vocabulário Oficial da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/vocabulario-ortografico) em 2009, que foi imediatamente aceita no país como oficial e já alcançou sua 5ª edição. Divergências internas entre a Academia de Ciências de Lisboa e o Instituto Camões abriu a brecha para o Instituto de Linguística Teórica e Computacional publicar o [Vocabulário Ortográfico Português](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/) em 2010, mas o [reconhecimento por parte do governo português](http://archive.is/yYg7i) só veio em 2011.

A Galiza, que não é signatária do Acordo, produziu em 2011 o [Léxico da Galiza](https://www.academiagalega.org/lexico-da-galiza.html), com 800 palavras a serem incluídas em ambos os Vocabulários. O órgão responsável pela obra é a Academia Galega da Língua Portuguesa, já que o país não reconhece o português como língua oficial.

Moçambique decidiu basear-se nos vocabulários português e europeu para lançar seu próprio [Vocabulário Ortográfico Nacional de Moçambique](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=von&von=mz) em 2016. Diferentemente dos demais vocabulários, o país decidiu publicar sob selo governamental, em vez de acadêmico. O Timor-Leste teve seu [Vocabulário Ortográfico Nacional de Timor-Leste](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=von&von=tl) criado pela CPLP em 2015 e revisado pelo Instituto Nacional de Linguística de Timor-Leste e pela Universidade Nacional de Timor Lorosa’e.

Os demais [países signatários](http://file:///D:/Users/Ramon/Downloads/ProtoModificAcOrtLPort.pdf) (Angola, Cabo Verde, Guiné-Bissau, São Tomé e Príncipe) estão no processo de compor seus próprios vocabulários. A CPLP disponibiliza o [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum](http://voc.cplp.org/) como forma de mitigar as diferenças regionais. Entretanto, esta obra não possui valor legal ou de normatização, já que cada país decide o Vocabulário que vai adotar a nível de governo federal.

Vale lembrar que os países possuíam prazos distintos para a ratificação do Acordo Ortográfico, e os termos relacionados ao Vocabulário eram vagos e passíveis de interpretações distintas. O fato de ter sido publicado antes ou depois não provê maior ou menor validade a qualquer dos Vocabulários.