# Onde se localiza o site/documento oficial da Norma Culta?

Tags: recursos, norma-culta, norma

As regras gramaticais do português, pelo que ouvi, estão na Norma Culta. Eu e quem conheço já ouvimos falar sobre a Norma Culta, mas sempre como normalmente ouvimos das leis: por outros e como Jackie Estripador: por partes. Mas, a Norma Culta, com tanta importância (assim como as leis), não deve ser assim. Digo, se ela tem o poder de definir o certo e o errado num texto, teria de ser bem documentada. Então, a minha pergunta: onde está a Norma Culta?

Comment: A norma culta é um conjunto de regras e ela está nas gramáticas, no decreto nº 6.583 etc. P.S.: Jack Estripador não esquartejava, mas estripava.

Comment: Valdeir, obrigado, vou checar isso. E a frase do Jackie Estripador que eu disse é uma frase comum de se ouvir, mas tem sentido o que disseste.

Comment: E por sinal, eu acho que decretos são escritos com sua primeira letra maiúscula, por exemplo, "Decreto 6.583.". Eu sei que estou sendo chato.

Comment: Está correta. Decreto, lei, medida provisória são em maiúscula, mas somente em duas ocasiões: quando tiver nome ou quando for numerada. Aqui é um site sobre a língua portuguesa, nada mais justo que pontuar alguns erros. :)

Comment: O decreto que disseste é sobre o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990. Quais são as outras? Da gramática, por exemplo.

Comment: Tem também o [Manual de Redação da Presidência da República](http://www4.planalto.gov.br/centrodeestudos/assuntos/manual-de-redacao-da-presidencia-da-republica/manual-de-redacao.pdf), que reúne regras e normas; esse, no entanto, é obrigatório apenas para documentos oficiais do governo.

Comment: Obrigado. Onde achaste esses documentos/leis, se não for incômodo?

Comment: Essas são as que conheço. As leis e os decretos do Brasil podem ser encontrados no site da Câmara e Senado Federal, Congresso Nacional e Planalto. Mas, em regra, é mais fácil encontrar as regras da norma culta nas gramáticas.

Comment: Obrigado, Valdeir Psr. Mas o que é/são as gramáticas?

Comment: É uma pergunta que não cabe num comentário. Mas, de forma resumida, as gramáticas são um conjunto de regras que trata sobre a linguagem escrita, falada e interiorizada. Gramáticas conhecidas: Moderna Gramática Portuguesa — Evanildo Bechara; Para Falar e Escrever Melhor o Português — Gama Kury; Gramática normativa da língua portuguesa — Rocha Lima; Gramática da língua portuguesa — Pasquale Neto.

Comment: Obrigado, Valdeir Psr. Eu nunca ouvi alguém dizendo "as gramáticas".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei um vídeo do linguista [Carlos Alberto Faraco, *Norma Culta Brasileira*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo3XUQNu_7w&list=PLJTYyIbC0Twny_SDAIF-aMmR0EAy3gpFJ), que é muito relevante para esta questão. Eu aconselho quem estiver interessado nesta coisas a assistir à lição toda (cerca de uma hora), e cito aqui algumas partes. Temos de começar com o conceito de ***norma normal**:*

> Podemos conceituar a **norma normal** como constituída por um conjunto de fenómenos linguísticos, fonológicos, morfológicos, sintáticos, lexicais, que são correntes, costumeiros, habituais, próprios, comuns, entre os falantes de um determinada comunidade de fala

O autor explica que existem diversas normas normais rurais, normas normais urbanas, juvenis, etc. Agora podemos passar à norma culta:

> A **norma culta** é uma das muitas normas normais, típica da população urbana, em nível de escolaridade de médio-alto, e usada em situações monitoradas de fala ou de escrita […] E nós entendemos por situações mais monitoradas, aquelas em que prestamos atenção à forma da nossa fala ou da nossa escrita. E prestamos atenção porque se trata de situações interacionais marcadas por formalidade […] a norma culta não é homogénea. Ela varia estilisticamente. Ou seja ela comporta diferenças ente fala e escrita, mas também diferenças entre os géneros textuais.

Daqui se conclui que a norma culta não é, nem pode ser, regulada por entidade nenhuma. Não é, por exemplo, como as normas definidas pela Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas. A norma culta emerge de uma comunidade de falantes e é demasiado heterogénea e dinâmica para poder ser listada num site.

Nós temos o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, aprovado por lei, que determina a ortografia oficial. Que eu saiba, este é o único aspeto da língua regulado por lei. Mas é no mínimo duvidoso que a norma culta exija que se siga a ortografia oficial. Em Portugal, vários jornais e autores continuaram a publicar na ortografia antiga. Estamos a falar de escrita monitorada de gente urbana e instruída, logo é norma culta de acordo com a definição acima. Não deixaria de o ser de um dia para o outro só por causa da entrada em vigor do Acordo Ortográfico. Eu estou especialmente à vontade para afirmar isto, porque eu sigo o Acordo.

O ortografia oficial pertence é à norma padrão, que não é o mesmo que norma culta. Voltando a citar Carlo Faraco:

> Enquanto a norma culta é a expressão viva, dinâmica, fluida de certos segmentos sociais em determinadas situações, a norma padrão é uma codificação relativamente abstrata, uma baliza teoricamente extraída do uso real para servir de referência a projetos políticos de uniformização linguística.

Portanto não há um site que contenha toda a norma culta. Em caso de dúvida, tens os dicionários e gramáticas. Nota no entanto que dicionários e gramáticas podem ser excessivamente conservadores. As gramáticas tendem a mostrar a norma padrão. Ora Carlos Faraco explica que nos debates em finais do século XIX e princípios do XX no Brasil, venceu a posição que a norma padrão do português brasileiro seguiria os padrões de escrita dos escritores portugueses do Romantismo, padrões esses que já então se desviavam do modo de expressão culto dos brasileiros, gerando as muitas diferenças entre a norma padrão e linguagem comum, no Brasil, mesmo na norma culta.

Answer (score -1):

Se a pergunta é onde estão as regras da norma culta, como já responderam nos comentários, essas regras estão documentadas e compiladas nas gramáticas e são publicadas sobre a forma de Decretos de Lei (como o Decreto n.º 6583, que estabelece o Novo Acordo Ortográfico em Vigor). A Academia Portuguesa de Lisboa lançou um [dicionário digital](https://volp-acl.pt/) com as normas em vigor atualmente, por força do acordo (e que, portanto, contem aquilo que constitui a norma culta atual).

Em relação a quem as define, as entidades reguladores indicadas na Wikipedia são    a Academia das Ciências de Lisboa e Academia Brasileira de Letras (para português-europeu e brasileiro, respetivamente), mas sugiro que veja as respostas a esta questão, que já estão detalhadas e com fontes: [Quem define as regras ortográficas entre Brasil e Portugal?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/quem-define-as-regras-ortogr%C3%A1ficas-entre-brasil-e-portugal)

Comment: Tu dizes "essas regras ... são publicadas sob a forma de Decretos de Lei (como o Decreto ...)"; o "como" sugere que existem outros decreto que regulam a norma culta. Existem mesmo? Eu não sei de mais nenhum. Pode ser que haja, mas então gostaria de ver mais exemplos. O que tu chamas "dicionário digital" não é um dicionário: só indica a grafia oficial e a classificação gramatical. E acerca de conter "aquilo que constitui a norma culta", a norma culta não se resume a ortografia e classificação gramatical das palavras; e encontras lá palavrões que não fazem parte da norma culta.