# Quem somos para as regras gramaticais?

Tags: norma-culta, norma

Venho a ler Moderna Gramática Portuguesa de Bechara.

No livro, se fala que "propriíssimo" é correto, mas cita que Dias Gomes escrevia "propríssimo"; porém, não diz que Dias Gomes estava errado, diz "a língua padrão insiste no atendimento à manutenção dos dois ii". Não se diz "errado" de "propríssimo", apenas que há uma insistência da língua padrão a "ií".

Parece que Bechara tem um tom mais descritivo, porém seu livro é usado como referência do correto. Se alguém escrever "propríssimo", um professor o/a tacha de burro e inculto; mas não diria o mesmo de Dias Gomes.

Por que isso acontece tanto? Digo, qual diferença entre a Maria escrever "propríssimo" e Dias Gomes escrever "propríssimo"?

P.S.: eu coloquei esse título, pois, não consegui pensar num que seja melhor.

Comment: O Evanildo Bechara é tido como uma referência mas alguns aspectos (detalhes) da sua obra são considerados controversos. É preciso ter em conta que na época em que o autor escreveu as gramáticas de referência para o português contemporâneo eram escassas. O mercado editorial era completamente diferente. Também, a linguística enquanto campo científico a nivel internacional teve um forte crescimento na década de 60. Hoje pode parecer que esses autores estavam errados mas são aspectos sobre os quais eles decidiram pronunciar-se e que sem reunir consenso dão margem para discussão.

Comment: @bad_coder, eu não estava dizendo que Bechara está (ava) errado. Estou dizendo que o livro não disse que A em vez de B era errado, um livro que é referência para muitas pessoas; mas que muitas dessas pessoas tacham quem usa A de burro, porém jamais falariam o mesmo de Dias Gomes. Eu não estava falando especificamente de "í" em vez de "ií". Desculpa, se não escrevi bem a pergunta; eu estou com sono.

Comment: Não tem problema, foi só um comentário (para dar um contexto histórico ao autor). Acho a pergunta boa e estou interessado em ver as respostas que possa ter. Gosto da obra do Evanildo Bechara mas calhou nunca ser a minha gramática de referência, vou revisitando os livros dele sem ter um conhecimento profundo.

Comment: @bad_code, qual é a tua gramática de referência? Estou perguntando, pois, será o próximo item da minha lista de leitura.

Comment: Eu gosto da ["Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo"
de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-nova-gramatica-do-portugues-contemporaneo-e-a-gramatica-da-lingua-portuguesa/20746) sei que há obras melhores e mais modernas, mas continua a ser a minha primeira escolha porque gosto. A obra sempre foi louvada, apesar das críticas. Não é um tratado de linguística, muito menos com a terminologia mais moderna. É limitado em muitos aspectos, mas continua a ser uma referência. Também é livro muito comum, se procurares no sebo encontras barato.

Comment: @bad_code, 'b'igado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tratamento do assunto pelo Bechara é razoabilíssimo. Taxar de erro todo e qualquer desvio à norma padrão é tacanhez. E se o professor procede assim com a Mariazinha, certamente não é o Bechara que tem a culpa.

Para quem ainda não viu, vale a pena ver por inteiro o que diz o Bechara ([Moderna Gramática Portuguesa](https://issuu.com/apogeu/docs/moderna_gramatica_portuguesa_-_evan_29dd2316c7b5c8/129)) acerca do sufixo -*íssimo:*

> Observação: Chamamos a atenção para as palavras terminadas em -*io* que, na forma sintética, apresentam dois *is*, por seguirem a regra geral da queda do -*o* final para receber o sufixo:
>           cheio → cheiíssimo, cheiinho
>           feio → feiíssimo, feiinho
>           frio → friíssimo, friinho
>           necessário → necessariíssimo
>           precário → precariíssimo
>           sério → seriíssimo
>           sumário → sumariíssimo
>           vário → variíssimo
> Observação: a tendência da língua à fuga ao hiato leva a que apareçam formas com fusão dos dois ii, embora num ou outro adjetivo a eufonia impede a mudança: **fríssimo*, **varíssimo*, por exemplo, embora Dias Gomes (séc. XVIII) escrevesse *propríssimo*. Ainda que escritores usem formas com um só *i* (*cheíssimo, cheinho, feíssimo, seríssimo*, etc.), a língua padrão insiste no atendimento à manutenção dos dois ii.

Portanto o Bechara descreve a norma padrão, dois ii, e a escrita desviante só com um i de alguns escritores. Agora, é preciso ver a natureza da norma padrão e desvios a ela. A língua compreende, e sempre compreendeu, muitas variedades; uma dessas variedade é a norma culta, que compreende, ela mesma, grande diversidade. Dessa variada norma culta extrai-se a norma padrão. Nas palavras do Prof. Carlos Alberto Faraco (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/onde-se-localiza-o-site-documento-oficial-da-norma-culta), em que eu tratei esta questão mais desenvolvidamente):

> a norma padrão é uma codificação relativamente abstrata, uma baliza teoricamente extraída do uso real para servir de referência a projetos políticos de uniformização linguística.

Algumas pessoas, como o proverbial professor da Mariazinha, parecem querer inverter isto. Parecem pensar que a língua começa com a norma padrão, como se a língua tivesse sido criada a régua e esquadro por uma comissão de sábios, e que qualquer desvio a essa norma padrão é um erro; é as pessoas que não sabem falar.

Mas um desvio à norma padrão pode ser simplesmente uma parte dessa diversidade, que existe mesmo dentro da norma culta, que ficou de fora da norma padrão. No caso em apreço encontra-se no uso culto formas com dois ii e com um só i. A norma padrão elegeu a forma com dois ii. É possível que tenha sido esta a forma mais comum no passado; uma busca sumariíssima no Google Books para isso aponta (mas, possível exceção, nos século XIX só encontrei *sumaríssimo*, não *sumariíssimo*). Os dois ii podem ser enquadrados numa regra geral: quando o adjetivo termina em vogal simples *a, e* ou *o*, a vogal cai e acrescenta-se -*íssimo* (*belo → belíssimo*), como menciona o Bechara. Como este sufixo foi introduzido na língua tardiamente por via culta, é natural que a aplicação de uma regra geral tenha tido peso. E nalguns casos os dois ii são indispensáveis: ninguém entenderia **fríssimo* ou **píssimo;* tem de ser *friíssimo* e *piíssimo* (de *pio*).

Portanto a norma padrão elegeu uma derivação regular: cai a vogal final e acrescenta-se o sufixo. Mas mesmo na expressão culta, surgiram formas com um só i por razões de eufonia, que têm vindo a ser crescentemente adotadas. Quer-me parecer que mesmo a norma padrão — o que dizem as gramáticas e dicionários — está em fluxo, e que o Bechara está no extremo mais conservador. No dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) e no [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum da CPLP](https://voc.cplp.org/index.php?sel=exact&action=simplesearch&base=form&query=necessar%C3%ADssimo) encontrei apenas formas com os dois ii, mas existem já gramáticos que vão mais longe que o Bechara, e dizem não só que há escritores que usam formas com um só i, mas, explicitamente, que as duas formas são aceitáveis. Ver artigo [do Prof. Pasquale na Folha de S. Paulo](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff2001200009.htm) e [estoutro da Cláudia Pinto no FLiP](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/4931).

Comment: Obrigado, @Jacinto. Por sinal, eu não tinha quisto dizer que Bechara estava errado, mas acho que me expressei mal.

Comment: @Schilive, não entendi que quisesses dizer que o Bechara estava errado; mais que ele tinha dado tratamento especial ao Gomes Dias.

Comment: eu quis dizer que Prof. Joana chamaria a Mariazinha de errada e inculta se escrevesse "propríssimo", mas nunca chamaria Gomes Dias de errado e inculto; enquanto um livro de gramática não chamaria nem a Mariazinha, nem Gomes de errados e incultos.

Comment: @Schilive, foi a pensar nesse tipo de professor que eu escrevi "Algumas pessoas parecem querer inverter isto". Vou meter isto mesmo na resposta.